# Adding If/End If to macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to add a condition to a copy and paste macro where it copies a row from table1 and pastes it onto table2 if the row in table1 is red.

I've tried:

```
Sub ColdLake1()

If Range("B55").Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then

    Range("B55:H55").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("C140").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
        , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False      
        End If
End Sub
```

It returns nothing. Any ideas?

Thanks (I'm quite new to all this).

Comment: What are you expecting it to return? `Sub` procedures never return values. `Function` procedures do.

Comment: prefix your Range("B55") and Range("B55:H55") with the worksheet that those ranges are (or activate that sheet in the top of your sub). If you don't then you might not have that worksheet activated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Sub ColdLake1()
    With ActiveSheet
        Debug.Print "ColorIndex", .Range("B55").Interior.ColorIndex
        If .Range("B55").Interior.ColorIndex = 3 Then
            .Range("B55:H55").Copy
            With .Range("C140")
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, _
                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
                    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If your code isn't doing anything it may be because the color isn't what you think it is, or for some reason your code is not entering the `If` block.  Put some breakpoints and see what is going on.  https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html

Comment: It turns out my code wasn't doing anything because I used conditional formatting on the tables I was trying to copy and excel doesn't recognize the changed colour. Thanks for the input!